# Java - Count Number of days except Holidays(Saturday and Sunday)

Tags: java, date, dayofweek

I need to count for number of days except holidays(Saturday and sunday). For example my start date is `07/02/2018` and end date is `15/02/2018` (in `dd/MM/yyyy` format). I need to count number of working days between them. Can some please help me out? This is my code:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateformat3 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

//Date date12 = dateformat3.parse("17/07/1989");
String date1 = "11/07/2018";
String date2 = "20/07/2018";

// Date date2 = dateformat3.parse("15/10/2007");
Calendar startdate = Calendar.getInstance();
startdate.setTime(dateformat3.parse(date1));
Calendar enddate = Calendar.getInstance();
enddate.setTime(dateformat3.parse(date2));
while (!startdate.after(enddate)) {
    int day = startdate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
    if ((day != Calendar.SATURDAY) && (day != Calendar.SUNDAY)) {
        workingDays++;
    }
}
```

I've tried with this code but is not showing any result.

Comment: The fact that within your while loop there's nothing to increment startdate is a key aspect of your problem I think...

Comment: "_it is not showing any result_" There is nothing in the code which should display anything.

Comment: FYI, you are using troublesome old date-time classes that are now legacy, supplanted by the *java.time* classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close, just need to increment start date inside while loop.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(countDays("07/02/2018", "15/02/2018"));
}

public static int countDays(String startDate, String endDate) throws Exception {
    int workingDays = 0;

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

    Calendar startdate = Calendar.getInstance();
    startdate.setTime(sdf.parse(startDate));
    Calendar enddate = Calendar.getInstance();
    enddate.setTime(sdf.parse(endDate));

    while (!startdate.after(enddate)) {
        int day = startdate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
        System.out.println(day);
        if ((day != Calendar.SATURDAY) && (day != Calendar.SUNDAY)) {
            workingDays++;
        }

        // increment start date, otherwise while will give infinite loop
        startdate.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    }

    return workingDays;
}
```

As you can see, the only difference with the code I provided from yours (besides removing hard-coded values)  is `startdate.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Java 8 you can use :

```
//Here I change the format of date to make it parsable
String date1 = "2018-07-11";
String date2 = "2018-07-20";

//Parse the date to LocalDate
LocalDate start = LocalDate.parse(date1);
LocalDate end = LocalDate.parse(date2);

//iterate over the list of dates between start and end date, 
//then filter only those who are not equal SATURDAY or SUNDAY, then count the result

long result = Stream.iterate(start, date -> date.plusDays(1))
        .limit(ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(start, end))
        .filter(date -> date.getDayOfWeek() != DayOfWeek.SATURDAY
                && date.getDayOfWeek() != DayOfWeek.SUNDAY
        ).count();
```

---

In your case it will return 7 days

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing wrong with your while condition. 
Try this

```
 while (ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(startdate.toInstant(), enddate.toInstant()) > 0) {
    startdate.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    if (startdate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) != Calendar.SATURDAY && startdate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) != Calendar.SUNDAY) {
      workingDays++;
    }
}
```